# Is there a function in xcode that provides you with how long the app has been working?

Tags: ios, xcode, time

Is there a function or a class reference in xcode that provides you with how long the app has been working ?? instead of doing it manually by  storing the value of NSDate once the app starts and then subtracting it from the current time

Update : I found the following method

```
in viewdidload
initial= [NSDate date];// stores the initial time

Once a button is pressed 
 NSLog(@"%f", [next timeIntervalSinceDate:initial]);// this displays the time since the start of the app
```

my problem now is how to sotre the value that I printed in a variable called current

```
current =[next timeIntervalSinceDate:initial];
```

I'm getting this error :Assigning to 'NSTimeInterval *' (aka 'double *') from incompatible type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double')

where all of the variables are defined as follows :

```
NSDate *initial;
NSDate *next;
NSTimeInterval *current;
```

I tried to change NSTimeInterval *current; to double but still same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the pointer asterisk. It's trying to tell you so. (aka 'double *') vs (aka 'double'). Remove the asterisk when you declare the variable. NSTimeInterval *current; should be NSTimeInterval current; Primitives don't use pointers the same way objects do.